# In EMF how can we add one feature in multiple featuregroup?

Tags: eclipse, frameworks, modeling, eclipse-emf

I have a feature named "Player" which I want to add to two feature groups.
General and Current, I tried it by giving comma-separated values.
like this: 
but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I tried giving comma-separated values for feature groups

Comment: key="featureGroup" value="Current,General"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Possible answer -> https://www.oiloftrop.de/code-research/emf-and-xsd-how-to-add-values-to-a-feature-map/